# Format of Sql DateTime object

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> CAST(IH.InvoiceDate AS date) AS InvoiceDate

this returns **2012-03-16** is it possible to format this in the select statement to return **16/03/2012**

I'm using Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: Any reason you don't want to do this in the client code? Normally that would be more appropriate - only convert to text as close to a user (or other system which requires it) as possible.

Comment: it is used in multiple places and programs and so far the time part has just been hidden on the interface. (it was originally just IH.InvoiceDate) and I thought that the best place to modify it without effecting any part of the programs would be in the select statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that format you'll need to convert it to a `VARCHAR` and apply a format. In this case, format `103` will output the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(IH.InvoiceDate AS DATE), 103) AS InvoiceDate
```

Assuming that `InvoiceDate` is a `DateTime` type, you can get rid of the cast too:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, IH.InvoiceDate, 103) AS InvoiceDate
```

Answer (score 7):

you have to use the `convert` function

```
declare @date datetime

set @date='2012-03-16 '

SELECT convert(varchar, @date, 103)
```

for further reference below you can find all the possible format for a date

```
100 – mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM (or PM)
    – Oct  2 2008 11:01AM          
101 – mm/dd/yyyy - 10/02/2008                  
102 – yyyy.mm.dd – 2008.10.02           
103 – dd/mm/yyyy
104 – dd.mm.yyyy
105 – dd-mm-yyyy
106 – dd mon yyyy
107 – mon dd, yyyy
108 – hh:mm:ss
109 – mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmmAM (or PM)
    – Oct  2 2008 11:02:44:013AM   
110 – mm-dd-yyyy
111 – yyyy/mm/dd
112 – yyyymmdd
113 – dd mon yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm
    – 02 Oct 2008 11:02:07:577     
114 – hh:mm:ss:mmm(24h)
120 – yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)
121 – yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm
126 – yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm
     – 2008-10-02T10:52:47.513
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `convert` with style 103 for French/British format:

```
CONVERT(Date, IH.InvoiceDate, 103) AS InvoiceDate
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert it to a string to get it displayed ad dd/mm/yyyy (no need for the interim cast);

```
convert(varchar(10), IH.InvoiceDate, 103) AS InvoiceDate
```

Answer (score 2):

use style 103

```
convert(varchar(10), IH.InvoiceDate, 103) as InvoiceDate
```

Here are two useful links regarding formatting date & time:

[how to format date & time](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

[SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)